# Select 100 results order by higher matching from 30 columns

Tags: mysql

Here is the Table (answers for 30 fixed questions, yes/no type answer)

```
id | us_id | q01 | q02 | q03 | q04 | q05 | q06 |...continue...| q30   
 1 |  139  |  1  |  1  |  0  |  1  |  1  |  1  |..............|  1  
 2 |  120  |  0  |  0  |  1  |  1  |  0  |  0  |..............|  0 
 3 |  155  |  1  |  0  |  0  |  1  |  0  |  1  |..............|  1 
 4 |  211  |  0  |  0  |  1  |  0  |  0  |  1  |..............|  1 
 5 |  112  |  1  |  1  |  1  |  1  |  0  |  1  |..............|  0 
 6 |  296  |  1  |  1  |  0  |  1  |  1  |  1  |..............|  1 
 7 |  421  |  0  |  1  |  1  |  1  |  0  |  0  |..............|  0 
 8 |  101  |  1  |  1  |  1  |  1  |  0  |  1  |..............|  0 
 9 |  986  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  1  |  1  |..............|  1 
10 |  997  |  1  |  1  |  0  |  1  |  0  |  1  |..............|  0 
11 |  474  |  1  |  1  |  1  |  1  |  0  |  0  |..............|  1 
12 |  881  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  1  |  1  |  1  |..............|  1 
xx |  yyy  |    ..up to fifty thousand rows... |..............|  x
```

user (example:us_id 112) would like to get 100 result ordered by best match with him (q01 to q30 columns to match). Highest percentage of match should return first. Questions are fixed, a separate table used for questions. answers are fixed type (yes/no). User himself also answered the questions (here user id=112) and try to find out who are his best match *means* who answered similar to him or nearly same or as maximum as possible.

Please help me make the query

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE _condition_ ORDER BY _matching condition_ LIMIT 0,100
```

I don't know *conditions* to put
Please help....

Comment: Properly sql query is not enough for this situations

Comment: do you mean the row that have 1 ones more get first?

Comment: @FarhadHossain If I were you I would load all recorders as array and do the calculations on other language

Comment: id 15 has q01=1 then all q01 with value 1 will come first and q02=0 then all q02 with value 0 comes first the same way q03 and rest @Gouda Elalfy

Comment: I have already answered this in question you deleted.

Comment: you are not clear, if q01= 1, q02=1 and q01=1, q02 = 0 what is coming first?

Comment: @Rezvan_Manolescu really sorry, it was suggested to make specific and the question was not making good sense, would you please do it here

Comment: Question answered under http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34379837/select-highest-matching-results-from-n-columns

Comment: Does this answer your initial problem?

Comment: @Razvan Manolescu thanks for replying me every time I need it. facts: questions are fixed, I can use a separate table for questions. answers are fixed (yes/no). user himself also answered the questions (here user id=15) and try to find out who are his best match *means* who answered similar like him or nearly same or as maximum as possible. I wish you got it.

Comment: You can store answers directly as acumulators so you can natively apply binary operators to them. You can have a separate question table for historical reasons. As I said, answer is under : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34379837/select-highest-matching-results-from-n-columns. I have re-posted this so other people may contribute and benefit from the answers.

Comment: Normalise your data - but properly - so not in the way Razvan suggests.

Comment: @Rezvan your solution is not working I checked

Comment: @Strawberry any clear suggestion please.

Comment: Yes. 1. See normalisation 2. Normalise your data 3. Then get back to us with any remaining problems

Comment: @Strawberry more normalisation will result 30 rows to match with each user who has also 30 rows, can't solve it really. The question was edited.

Comment: Correct. That is what a normalised schema would look like.

Answer (score 0):

> Try this

I checked this query with 9 question and 10 user and It's worked

> select *,(q1+q2+q3+q4+q5+q6+q7+q8+q9...........q30) as total from
>   questions having total = (select
>   (q1+q2+q3+q4+q5+q6+q7+q8+q9..............q30) as total2 from questions
>   where us_id=112) limit 100;

Comment: q1+q2 will not solve the issue. us_id 112 may answered first 15 questions yes=1 but some users answered last 15 questions yes=1, the query will return them which is 100% opposite to expectation.

Answer (score 0):

you can order q01 column then order q02 and this way you can order top matching first less matching next.

Answer (score -1):

```
query >>> SELECT *,(q01+q02+q03......+q30) as total FROM table ORDER BY total DESC LIMIT 0,100
```

Comment: Thanks for answering but things are not so easy. say us_id 112 has all answer zero and the expected result should be zero or near to zero not the highest value after summation.